# Displaying A, B, C, D Labels In Order: Swift

Tags: swift

I have created something like a quiz game where it displays A, B, C, D. The problem is that it displays A, B, C, D out of order.

[image]

This is the code that I use to display them:

```
for (buttonIndex, value) in model.answers.enumerated() {
        let id = value.key
        let answer = value.value

        answersKeys.append(id)
        print(id)

        let answerLabel = UILabel()
        answerLabel.text = answer

        let answerButton = UIButton()
        let imageNormal = UIImage(named: "circle_empty")
        let imageSelected = UIImage(named: "circle_filled")

        answerButton.setImage(imageNormal, for: .normal)
        answerButton.setImage(imageSelected, for: .selected)
        answerButton.tag = buttonIndex // (2) store current button index as tag
        answerButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        answerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        answersStack.addArrangedSubview(answerLabel)
        answersStack.addArrangedSubview(answerButton)


    }
```

I use a database to call them from, and I have checked that the database shows them correctly (It shows it in order) This probably is very easy fix, but have not been able to find a solution. Your help would greatly appreciated. ~ Thanks

Comment: According to what I'm seeing in your code, the `model` variable is a `Dictionary` isn't? `Dictionary` is an unordered data structure, so when you inserted the values it doesn't mean that it comes in the same order

Comment: Have you checked whether enumerating them actually prints them out in order? That may be the reason for the issue you're seeing

Comment: Yeah in the console it prints the order it is displaying, but I don't know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the code, you provide above your `mode` variable is a `Dictionary` type as you're calling the `key` and `value` properties.

So as I mentioned before in my comment, the `Dictionary` type is an unordered data structure, so when you inserted the values it doesn't mean that it comes in the same order you inserted. Let's see the following example:

```
let dict: [Int: String] = [
   0: "D",
   1: "A",
   2: "C",
   3: "B"
]

print(dict.enumerated().map { ($0, $1) })
```

This print to the console:

```
[(0, (key: 2, value: "C")), (1, (key: 0, value: "D")), (2, (key: 1, value: "A")), (3, (key: 3, value: "B"))]
```

As you can see the order of the values are completely different as we inserted in the dictionary.

So if you sort the enumeration you can have your expected result of ordering regarding its value, see the following example:

```
print(dict.enumerated().sorted { $0.0.element.value < $0.1.element.value })
```

This print to the console:

```
[(offset: 2, element: (key: 1, value: "A")), (offset: 3, element: (key: 3, value: "B")), (offset: 0, element: (key: 2, value: "C")), (offset: 1, element: (key: 0, value: "D"))]
```

The enumeration of the `dict` is ordered by its value.

So if we apply the same logic and we make a `map` to omit the `offset` we can get the following code:

```
let orderedDict = dict.enumerated().sorted { $0.0.element.value < $0.1.element.value }

for (index, value) in orderedDict {
   print(index, value.value)
}
```

And this print in the console the `offset` and `value` ordered by its `value`:

```
2 A
3 B
0 C
1 D
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: @josh I don't understand what do you mean, can you be more specific, please?

Comment: So I have a struct called Question. They have many things such as answers. when I put dict in there and then try to call it in Question Cell it is not able to find it. Error: Use of unresolved identifier

Comment: Do you understand what I am trying to ask?